# Не могу убрать расширение файла из имя файла помогите

Tags: javascript

Не могу убрать расширение файл из имя файла помогите

```js
var objectUrl;

$("#audio").on("canplaythrough", function(e){
    var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;
    var duration = moment.duration(seconds, "seconds");
    
    var time = "";
    var hours = duration.hours();
    if (hours > 0) { time = hours + ":" ; }
    
    time = time + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
    $("#duration").text(time);
    
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
});

$("#file").change(function(e){
    var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
   
    $("#filename").text(file.name);
    $("#filetype").text(file.type);
    $("#filesize").text(file.size);
    
    objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $("#audio").prop("src", objectUrl);
});
```

```css
audio {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Выберите файл .mp3</p>
<input type="file" id="file" />

<audio id="audio"></audio>

<p>
  <label>Имя файла:</label>
  <span id="filename"></span>
</p>

<p>
  <label>Тип файла:</label>
  <span id="filetype"></span>
</p>

<p>
  <label>Размер файла:</label>
  <span id="filesize"></span>
</p>

<p>
  <label>Продолжительность:</label>
  <span id="duration"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: А что, `substr` или `split` уже отменили?

Comment: Советую. Говорят помогает хорошо

Comment: А зачем вы привели всю эту портянку кода? Она не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самые простые варианты "влоб", на `javascript`.
.1. Если расширение точно будет 3 символа

```
var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
var extension = file.name.substr(file.name.length - 3);
```

.2.

```
var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
var extension = file.name.split('.').pop();
```